# How to extend the legend text lineheight with ploty in R?

Tags: plotly, line-height

guys, I got a fig with plotly in R, the legend text line height is too small,  [image]

What I want is a bigger line height as follows, many thanks for any kind help.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish that?

Comment: I tried lineheight, but did not work